# Generate Password Salt in ColdFusion equivalent to .NET Membership Password Salt

Tags: coldfusion, passwords, asp.net-membership, coldfusion-9, membership-provider

I have been searching for an equivalent of the below method/function from .NET for ColdFusion. I have ASP Membership tables with ASP.NET site running on the database. The same database is used for the ColdFusion site. The idea is to develop an ASP site with the current database that has been used by a ColdFusion site. The two sites will run parallel for at least 3-6 months, allowing a user to connect from either one. Creation of a user can also happen on either side. From .NET I have it sorted. But in ColdFusion I am still struggling.

```
private string GenerateSalt() {
        var buf = new byte[16];
        (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found something very simple. It may not be the same Crypto Service but it generate the same length and format as the one above.

```
GenerateSecretKey("AES")
```

Simple as that. Maybe this may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure CF equivalent. However, the java equivalent is [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

> A cryptographically strong random number minimally complies with the
>   statistical random number generator tests specified in [FIPS 140-2,
>   Security Requirements for Cryptographic Modules](http://csrc.nist.gov/cryptval/140-2.htm), section 4.9.1.
>   Additionally, SecureRandom must produce non-deterministic output.
>   Therefore any seed material passed to a SecureRandom object must be
>   unpredictable, and all SecureRandom output sequences must be
>   cryptographically strong, as described in [RFC 1750: Randomness
>   Recommendations for Security.](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1750.txt)

**Example:**

```
<cfscript>
    provider = createObject("java", "java.security.SecureRandom").getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    bytes = javacast("byte[]", listToArray(repeatString("0,", 16)));
    provider.nextBytes( bytes ) ;   
    saltInBase64 = binaryEncode( bytes, "base64");
</cfscript>
```

Comment: BTW: You *should* be able to call `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` from `createObject(".net")`, but .. it does not seem to work. No syntax errors, but it does not populate `buf` with random bytes. Not sure if it is an error on my part, or a bug.

Comment: Is there any limit on array length that can be defined in javacast byte[] ? Also I'm wondering if I pass array with set of characters (for example [83,34,54,56,34]) would that be any less secure way to generate random salt?